# How to show the company name next to the URL (HTTPS)?

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am using SSL on many website, but still i did not found any option to show company name next to the URL. How can i do that ?

Like this >

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to buy an Extended Validation (EV) certificate to get this. Here the certificate agency will do more than just automatically checking if you control the domain (i.e. domain validated (DV) certificate) but you have to actually send them various documents to prove that this is a company etc and your application will be manually validated. Of course such a certificate costs more.